# Mockito : java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to DataListListener

Tags: java, android, mockito

I'm trying to perform an unit test using mockito, but the test failed I 'am getting this :

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to
>   OnDataListListener

here in this line : `mPresenter.getUsers(isLoad, forceUpdate);`

The test :

```
 doAnswer(answerVoid(
        (OnDataListListener<List<User>> myCallback) -> myCallback.onSuccess(mList))).when(
        dataInteractor).getUsers(anyBoolean(), any(DataListener.class));

    mPresenter.getUsers(isLoad, forceUpdate);
```

Presenter

```
  @Override public void getUsers(boolean isLoad, boolean update) {
    this.isLoad = isLoad;
    this.forceUpdate = update;
    dataInteractor.performgetUsers(update, this);//this refer to the listener
  }
```

DataInteractor :

```
  public void performGetGetUsers(boolean update, OnDataListListener callback) {
    mDataHandler.getUsers(update, new Observer<List<User>>() {
....
```

The listener interface:

```
public interface DataListener<T> {
  void onSuccess(T data);

  void onFailure(Throwable e);
}
```

Comment: `.getUsers(anyBoolean(), any(DataListener.class))` should probably be `.getUsers(anyBoolean(), anyBoolean())`

Comment: Can you post the signature of `DataInteractor#getUsers()`?

Comment: updated with more code

Comment: @RC no that one is correct, it should be a listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is so weird, but switching the params solved the issue !

```
dataInteractor.performgetUsers(update, this);//this refer to the listener
```

to

```
dataInteractor.performgetUsers(this, update);//this refer to the listener
```